# API docs generation tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, documentation

I have a RESTful API written on RubyOnRails(restfulie gem).
What is the best way to generate api documentation from project sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake doc:app` will turn your rdoc formatted comments for your methods into properly formatted html

Answer (score 1):

idlefingers has it right, but here is the complete answer for newbies:

1. Include rdoc in your Gemfile: gem "rdoc"
2. Run $ rake doc:app to generate the documentation
3. Access the rdoc by opening the doc/app/index.html file in your browser